# Calculate rating for 5 stars depending of reviews

Tags: php

I have good reviews, and I have bad reviews. I need calculate rating from this reviews for post.

Example:

- Post 1 have 1 good reviews, and 2 bad reviews
- Post 2 have 12 good reviews, and 5 bad reviews
- Post 3 have 0 good reviews, and 0 bad reviews

How I can calculate rating? I need for post get 5 stars. I need score up to 5 stars or less. May be I need this formula?

```
$score = ($good_reviews * $bad_reviews) / 5; //get rating stars
```

But I don't get 5, or less number. How I can do it correctly?

Comment: Calculating an average is basic arithmetic.  Take the sum of your values and divide by the count of your values.

Comment: @David Example I have 102 good reviews and 2 bad reviews, how then I can calculate? `$score = (102+2)/104` I get wrong value. I get 1.

Comment: Well, if the value of *every* review is 1 then the average of *all* reviews will certainly be 1.  What is the numeric value of a "good" review and what is the numeric value of a "bad" review in your case?

Comment: @David I have 102 good reviews, why I get rating 1? May be need to be 3.5 rating?

Comment: @David Example I have 0 bad reviews, then: `(102+0)/102` and I get `1`. Why??

Comment: You're asking why `102/102 = 1`?  Again, this is basic arithmetic.  What do you *expect* that expression to equal?

Comment: @David I want get rating equal to 5 or less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
 $rating = $good_reviews 
     ? intval ( 5.4 * $good_reviews / ( $good_reviews + $bad_reviews))
     : 0;
```

And now step by step:

- `SUM := $good_reviews + $bad_reviews` is the sum of all reviews.
- `RATE := $good_reviews / SUM` is the general rating of $good_reviews to the sum of reviews. The result is in the range 0.000 to 1.000 .
- Multiplying it with 5.4 expands the range to 0.000 to 5.400. Its a little bit tricky to allow some bad votes for a 5 stars ranking. The factor can be every number between 5.000 and 5.9999999.
- `intval()` reduces the number to an int from 0 to 5 (your stars).
- The alternative by `?:` avoids an division by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

That formula will not give you what you need. It will only multiply good with bad and divide by 5. For example ((100 good * 20 bad) / 5) = 400. Way out of 5!

If you need score up to five stars you will need to use ranges.

Calculate percentage between good and bad and then do an if checks.

For example:

```
$percentage = (($good - $bad) / $good) * 100;

if($percentage => 100) {
 //5 starts
} else if ($percentage < 100 && $percentage => 80) {
 //4 stars
} else if ($percentage < 80 && $percentage => 60) {
 //3 stars
} else if ($pecentage < 60 && $percentage => 40) {
 //2 starts
} else {
 //1 star
}
```

That's just a basic example. There are different ways to approach this. You need to adjust it to your needs and try if it works for you.

I did this really quick, so didn't test it. Please, check and see if it fits you. I just wanted to give you an idea.